# How can iOS figure out a video of H.263 codec

Tags: ios, video, edit

As asked above, before editing a video I want to know whether the video can be edited in iOS, in my situation, I need to filter out video of H.263 codec, but how to get a video's codec information explicitly?

Comment: Take a look at the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11194609/334402

Comment: @Mick thanks for your answer~